# Minimising the MPI broadcast for massive data

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, mpi, broadcast

I am making a large block of data in each process and I need to share these data between the processes by MPI broad casting,

How can I minimise the cost or is there any algorithm for broadcasting the massive data between processes by MPI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I minimise the cost or is there any algorithm for broadcasting
> the massive data between processes by MPI?

Bear in mind that [MPI_Bcast](https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-broadcast-and-collective-communication/):

> During a broadcast, one process **sends the same data to all processes
> in a communicator**.

If that is what you want you will have to rely on the underling hardware and on that the implementation of the MPI standard that you are using implements the [MPI_Bcast](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Bcast.html) routine efficiently. It might even happen that (depending upon your implementation) [MPI_Reduce is actually faster than MPI_Bcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007943/why-is-mpi-bcast-so-much-slower-than-mpi-reduce). Nevertheless, in some implementations, for instance Open MPI, you can further tune the algorithm used by the `MPI_Bcast` using the flag

```
--mca coll_tuned_use_dynamic_rules 1 --mca coll_tuned_bcast_algorithm 4
```

Another option is to try and use the non-blocking version of the MPI broadcast, namely [MPI_Ibcast](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Ibcast.html):

> Broadcasts a message from the process with rank "root" to all other
> processes of the communicator in a nonblocking way

You can try to overlap computation with communication. Notwithstanding, that computation should not modify the buffer used by the MPI routine (more information on why can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66229111/simple-hello-world-non-blocking-mpi/66231395#66231395)).

Comment: Do they have something like "--mca coll_tuned_use_dynamic_rules 1" in MPICH implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your network topology, you can use techniques to minimize the latency of sending large messages. For example, if your topology is a hierarchical one, you can implement the broadcast by multiple `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` operations.
In this regard and for having a better understanding of hierarchical broadcast, I suggest you take a look at this [link](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/349/introduction-to-mpi/broadcasting)

Apart from this, you can also use the asynchronous (Non-Blocking) version of MPI operations to improve the performance of transferring large data sizes.